# jQuery Datatables add row with data-sort attribute

Tags: datatables

I have to add a row to a jquery datatable dynamically. The problem is, that I have several cells with a `data-sort` attribute. How can I add that attributes to the added rows?

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Preis</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-sort="Max Müller">M. Müller</td>
            <td data-sort="500">5,00 €</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
table.row.add([
    'J. Wayne', // Here I need a data-sort="John Wayne"
    '6,00 €', // Here I need a data-sort="600"
]).draw();
```

Comment: **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286528/datatables-dynamically-add-row-with-fnadddata-or-similar-and-add-a-class-to-a-sp)** might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way would be to use a [**`createdRow`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback that automatically populates all `<td>` values with a `data-sort` attribute containing the column content :

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    data.forEach(function(str, idx) {
      $(row).find('td').eq(idx).attr('data-sort', str)
    })
  }
})
```

It is working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ea5ayzzb/**

Comment: Sounds good. Can I also add that callback after the initialization of the table like an event `table.on('draw.dt', myFunction);`? My table is created earlier.

Comment: @DominikBarann, I really dont get what you mean? You cannot add a callback once the table is created. but why would you do that?

Comment: The problem is, that I have a class `.data-table`. Every table with that class becomes a datatable with some default options. Now there is that one table where I need that callback and I can't reinit it, because it has already been initialised.