# DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0'

Tags: datatables

Does anybody please know, what is wrong with the very simple HTML file below?

[image]

I am just trying to use [an array of objects](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html) as the data source for DataTables:

**tests.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.2/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.2/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var data = [
                {"Name":"UpdateBootProfile","Result":"PASS","ExecutionTime":"00:00:00","Measurement":[]},
                {"Name":"NRB Boot","Result":"PASS","ExecutionTime":"00:00:50.5000000","Measurement":[{"TestName":"TOTAL_TURN_ON_TIME","Result":"PASS","Value":"50.5","LowerLimit":"NaN","UpperLimit":"NaN","ComparisonType":"nctLOG","Units":"SECONDS"}]},
                {"Name":"NvMgrCommit","Result":"PASS","ExecutionTime":"00:00:00","Measurement":[]},
                {"Name":"SyncNvToEFS","Result":"PASS","ExecutionTime":"00:00:01.2500000","Measurement":[]}
            ];

            $(function() {
                var testsTable = $('#tests').dataTable({
                    bJQueryUI: true,
                    aaData: data,
                    aoColumns: [
                        { mData: 'Name' },
                        { mData: 'Result' },
                        { mData: 'ExecutionTime' }
                    ]
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tests">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Result</th>
                <th>ExecutionTime</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, I've got the answer from the author [to use a newer version of DataTables or rename mData to mDataProp](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15519/requested-unknown-parameter-0390039-from-the-data-source-for-row-0390039)

Comment: I too was using the wrong version. Thanks.

Comment: Try to specify the **columns** parameter while initializing the data table. Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data#Examples

Comment: in my case it was allright with ajax but  from server I've sent to table an array. Had to send  array in array. I.e. rows in array !!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're using an array of objects.  Can you use a two dimensional array instead?

http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QhYse/

I used an array like this and it worked fine:

```
var data = [
    ["UpdateBootProfile","PASS","00:00:00",[]] ,
    ["NRB Boot","PASS","00:00:50.5000000",[{"TestName":"TOTAL_TURN_ON_TIME","Result":"PASS","Value":"50.5","LowerLimit":"NaN","UpperLimit":"NaN","ComparisonType":"nctLOG","Units":"SECONDS"}]] ,
    ["NvMgrCommit","PASS","00:00:00",[]] ,
    ["SyncNvToEFS","PASS","00:00:01.2500000",[]]
];
```

**Edit to include array of objects**

There's a possible solution from this question: [jQuery DataTables fnrender with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518989/jquery-datatables-fnrender-with-objects)

This jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j2C7j/ uses an array of objects.  To not get the error I had to pad it with 3 blank values - less than optimal, I know.  You may find a better way with fnRender, please post if you do.

```
var data = [
   ["","","", {"Name":"UpdateBootProfile","Result":"PASS","ExecutionTime":"00:00:00","Measurement":[]} ]

];

$(function() {
        var testsTable = $('#tests').dataTable({
                bJQueryUI: true,
                aaData: data,
                aoColumns: [
                        { mData: 'Name', "fnRender": function( oObj ) { return oObj.aData[3].Name}},
                        { mData: 'Result' ,"fnRender": function( oObj ) { return oObj.aData[3].Result }},
                        { mData: 'ExecutionTime',"fnRender": function( oObj ) { return oObj.aData[3].ExecutionTime } }
                ]
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks +1, but I'd like to use an array of objects, because of some features I plan to add later...

Comment: Thanks for vote. I've modified the answer to include array of objects.  Unfortunately have to pad with three blanks otherwise DataTables still complains.

Answer (score 170):

For ***null*** or ***undefined value*** error, Just add this line to attributes : `,columnDefs: [ { "defaultContent": "-", "targets": "_all" } ]`

Example :

```js
oTable = $("#bigtable").dataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all"
  }]
});
```

The alert box will not show again, any empty values will be replaced with what you specified.

Comment: I used this solution but without the quotes around "columnDefs". It worked great, thanks!!

Comment: Sme here!! Latest version doesn't require quotes around the property names in case anyone has this same issue.  Wish I saw this sooner, thank you soo much!!

Comment: It is what I was looking for. Big thanks!

Comment: This works but this also hides the actual problem. Better to find, format or fix the null source

Comment: You never require quotes around a property name unless it has a characters in it that would be invalid in a variable. That has nothing to do with the latest version. You never needed to use quotes.

Comment: This worked for me.  I was outputting 3 columns with one button per column.  However, not every row is going to have a button in one or two of those columns, so it was throwing an error due to the null content.

Answer (score 20):

This plagued me for over an hour.

If you're using the dataSrc option and column defs option, make sure they are in the correct locations. I had nested column defs in the ajax settings and lost way too much time figuring that out.

This is good:

[image: good]

This is not good:

[image]

Subtle difference, but real enough to cause hair loss.

Comment: @qwertzman sorry!! I was an hour behind on my work and wanted to get back to work asap but also wanted to leave my findings to save others the hour. I took the easy way out.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same problem. Turns out in my case, I was missing the comma after the last column. 30 minutes of my life wasted, I will never get back!

[image]

Comment: but what is solution?

Comment: @ImBS -  I didn't have a comma; I needed to add the comma at the end of the last brace.

Comment: adding those column devs is what fixed my problem!

Comment: columnDefs solved it for me. Go figure why the samples on DataTables.net don't need that.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the column names are the same. They are case sensitive. Here, in my case, i got this error when the column names of my model are in capitalzed and i used all the lower case letters in the data of ajax request.

So,i resolved by matching the column names exactly the same way as the existing model names.

**DataTable Binding**

```
$("#Customers").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/customers/",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: "Name",
                    render: function (data, type, customer) {
                        return "<a href='/customers/edit/" + customer.Id + "'>" + customer.Name + "</a>";


                    }

                },
                {
                    data: "Name"
                },
                {
                    data: "Id",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-customer-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

**Web API Method:**

```
  public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return _context.Customers.ToList();

        }
```

**My Model:-**

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }        

        [Display(Name="Date Of Birth")]        
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }


        public bool isSubscribedToNewsLetter { get; set; }

        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Membership Type")]
        [Required]
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

so here in my case, iam populating datatable with columns(Name,Name,Id).. iam duplicating the second column name to test.

Comment: Also, it is important to remember that you may have activated the camel case to your web api.

Comment: Bingo, in my case, it was the camelcase issue. Thank you @JeanJimenez

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common case in DataTables when it's not able to find the request field define in DataTable configuration.
**For Example:**

```
                "aoColumns": [{
                    mData: 'mobile', sWidth: "149px;"
               }, {
                    mData: 'name', sWidth: "121px;"
               }, {
                    mData: 'productName', sWidth: "116px;"
                            }
            }];
```

Here, If DataTable  doesn't receive above mentioned properties. It'll generate this warning: 
**DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0'**

To overcome this you just need to simply set a default value in "aoColumns"

**For Example:**

```
  "aoColumns": [{
                mData: 'mobile',sDefaultContent :  '',sWidth: "149px;"
           }, {
                mData: 'name',sDefaultContent :  '', sWidth: "121px;"
           }, {
                mData: 'productName',sDefaultContent :  '', sWidth: "116px;"
              }
        }];
```

**sDefaultContent** will supress the warning.

Note: This property could be changed based on version of dataTables you are using.

Answer (score 4):

I face this issue because I messed `return keyword` in `custom rendering` in `Columns section`

```
columns: [
    {....
        'data': function(row, type, val, meta) {
            if (row.LetterStatus)
                 return '@CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture()' == 'ar'? row.LetterStatus.NameInArabic: row.LetterStatus.NameInEnglish;
            else row.LetterStatusID.toString();// here is the problem because I messed the Return key keyword
          },
     ......
    }
```

the problem in my code is because I `messed` the `Return keyword` in the `else clause`

so I changed it to

```
....
else return row.LetterStatusID.toString();// messed return keyword added
.....
```

Comment: This was the reason in my case. It is weird that js errors in custom render are not showing...

Answer (score 3):

it's 2022 and I just stumbled upon this problem, fortunately easy to solve.

The issue is (most probably) that your `render` function does not return anything useful, BUT it has to (in all cases):

```
columns : [

    // ...

    {     
        // wrong, no state no return value, the result is the
        // warning pop up
        render : function(data, type, row, meta) {
            if (row.state) {
                return 'State is ' + row.state
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

]
```

This makes it go away:

```
columns : [

    // ...

    {     
        // this covers all cases
        render : function(data, type, row, meta) {
            if (row.state) {
                return 'State is ' + row.state
            }
            // in this example make sure that at least
            // something is returned
            return '';
        }
    }

    // ...

]
```

Alternatively you can add `defaultContent : ''` to you column definition, same effect.

Comment: Its end of 2022 and this helped me really quickly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From DataTables website:

> Each cell in DataTables requests data, and when DataTables tries to
>   obtain data for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a
>   warning, telling you that data is not available where it was expected
>   to be. The warning message is:
>
> DataTables warning: table id=`{id}` - Requested unknown parameter
>   '`{parameter}`' for row `{row-index}`
>
> where:
>
> `{id}` is replaced with the DOM id of the table that has triggered the error
>
> `{parameter}` is the name of the data parameter DataTables is requesting
>
> `{row-index}` is the DataTables internal row index for the rwo that has triggered the error.
>
> So to break it down, DataTables has requested data for a given row, of
>   the `{parameter}` provided and there is no data there, or it is `null` or
>   `undefined`.

See this [tech note](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) on DataTables web site for more information.

Comment: For me, it works fine with `null` but was throwing an error when the data array contained `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

In my weird scenario, I had a *different* column that didn't always return a value in the 'render' function. `return null` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `knockout.bindings.dataTables.js` then you can edit the file and replace this line

```
dataTable.fnAddData(unwrappedItems);
```

with

```
if (unwrappedItems.length > 0) {
    dataTable.fnAddData(unwrappedItems);
}
```

This has help me and i hope will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is using the new DataTables (which is awesome btw) and want to use array of objects then you can do so easily with the columns option. Refer to the following link for an excellent example on this.

[DataTables with Array of Objects](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

I was struggling with this for the past 2 days and this solved it. I didn't wanted to switch to multi-dimensional arrays for other code reasons so was looking for a solution like this.

Comment: You have stated that DataTables is awesome (I agree), added a link to one of the official examples and informed us how many days you struggled. But how does this answer my question?

Comment: Well if you'd access the link you would have found exactly how to use an array of objects correctly with the new DataTable. The example on the link shows how exactly to do that using the columns & data properties. Sorry but this site was made to help out, not to write the exact code for someone!!

Comment: Actually you need to write your solution here. link only answers are not advised in case after a while link go missing then your answer will be flagged to be deleted

[6th para in 1st answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)