# Jquery datatable 1.10.16 not binding Json Response to table

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my response from action method:

```
{
    "draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 2, "recordsFiltered": 2, "data": [
        { "ISIN": "IMF284L016", "SubSchemeName": "Geliance jocused Marge Map  Plan-Growth Option", "TotalAmountInvested": 400.0000, "CurrentValue": 507.402400, "Client": "23", "ClientName": "Lweta Kain      " },

        { "ISIN": "IKF24K01o", "SubSchemeName": "", "TotalAmountInvested": 0.0000, "CurrentValue": 0.000000, "Client": "23", "ClientName": "Uweta Kain      " }

    ]
}
```

Below is my code

```
$('#orderBookTable').DataTable({

            "pageLength": 50,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Fund/Get",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "Json",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.clientCode = $("#sltClientName").val();
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "SchemeName" },
                    { "data": "Client" },
                    { "data": "Invested" },
                    { "data": "CurrentValue" },
                    { "data": "CurrentValue" },
                ],
                "fnCreatedRow": function (d) {
                    debugger;
                }
            }
        });
```

please have look in to it.
My server side code returning JsonResult using Json method

Comment: Can you add code how you're binding the data and console error if any?

Comment: no there is no console error. But it shows pop up error "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16539578/3953479 this question has a similar error.

Comment: let me chek that question

Comment: I already went through that link ,   Now tell me how convert that response from Array of Objects to Array of Arrays

Comment: can you share your code, where you're trying to do that

Comment: I am using  Json(Model) this method to return my object

Comment: This is probably because you haven't set up your table to use objects - as you're returning objects in the JSON, you need to define the columns during the table initialisation.  See the example here: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: I already had define the columns like that but still data is not binding to data table

Comment: As Rajeev said, you need to share your table initialisation code - without it we're shooting blind...

Comment: Please look into client side code

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, you see. When you define the columns, you're telling DataTables where to get the data for that column. However, you haven't got a SchemeName or an Invested field in your returned data. There's a subSchemeName, but not SchemeName. All fields in the columns initialisation, must be in the returned JSON data.

Comment: I have change the properties still error is there

Answer (score 0):

As your response is complex JSON object, and as per documentation available [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html)  you should change your column initialization as below:

```
"columns": [
                { "data": "data.SchemeName" },
                { "data": "data.Client" },
                { "data": "data.Invested" },
                { "data": "data.CurrentValue" },
                { "data": "data.CurrentValue" },
            ],
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I have solved this issue By changing "bProcessing" to processing & "bServerSide" to ServerSide. I think that parameters not support in 1.10.18 version