# json issues with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the json coming as this

```
"{\"data\":[{\"Youtube\":\"CD7JYg1inF8\",\"ID\":1,\"Title\":\"New Zealand\",\"Description\":\"raceway.\}]}"
```

error i am getting is this

```
DataTables warning: table id=ivideos - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

i have the call code like thhis:

```
$('##ivideos').DataTable({
         'deferRender': true,
         'ajax': {
            'url': 'a.cfc?method=getvideos',
            "dataSrc": function (d) {
                return d
            }
         },
         'columns': [            
            { 'data': 'id' },
            { 'data': 'title' },
            { 'data': 'description' },
            { 'data': 'youtube' }
         ]
      }); //dataTable
```

using datatables version 1.10 onwards

Comment: Looks like it is `ID` in the source array,, not `id` ....

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with datatables, but it appears that column names are case sensitive as is usually the case with libraries, etc. that look for JSON properties. Fix the casing and try your method again. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42843244) for more details:

Comment: i tried with the casing too, but i am getting same error