# How can I populate selected files from HTML file type input tag into JQuery-DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to write a javascript to list all selected files in a Jquery datatable.

I am a newbie, I have searched a lot on internet about Jquery datatables but couldn't completely build the solution.
With the below javascript code, I get an alert  ***DataTables warning: table id=files-table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4***

Can somebody help me to complete this.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--{%  csrf_token %}-->
        <input type="file" name="document" multiple>
        <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
</form>

<table id="files-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
let table = $("#files-table").DataTable({
     columns: [
            { title: "S.No" },
            { title: "File Name" },
            { title: "File Size" }
        ]
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name=document]").change(function(){
    let slno = 1; 
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
        console.log($(this).get(0).files[i].name)
        row = []
        table.row.add(slno,$(this).get(0).files[i].name,$(this).get(0).files[i].size)
        table.draw();
        slno++; 
    }
  });

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539578/datatables-warning-requested-unknown-parameter-0-from-the-data-source-for-row)

Comment: @kartiktyagi Thanks. Let me check it out..